# What does Thunar's the red exclamation mark mean?

Tags: error-handling, thunar

This alarming-yet-opaque warning pictured below as the red circle background for a white exclamation point provided by the Thunar file manager, cropped up after doing a software upgrade.  Upon reboot several Thunar windows popped up in various directories with the same symbolic warning yet clicking on the icon yielded no information and searching Thunar's online help for "exclamation" produced "Nothing was found".

[image]